# Where is the manifest file C#

Tags: c#, .net

I am getting an error after converting a C# application from MSVS2003 to MSVS2010 :`"This application has failed to start because application configuration is incorrect. Review the manifest file for possible errors..."` when I try to run the application.  Where is the manifest file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an issue with your VC (not C#) runtime configuration. This MSDN thread should tell you what to do: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vcgeneral/thread/36971526-95f3-4a9f-a601-1843c86332c1